# Post Video On Twitter Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, twitter

Can anyone please tell me how i can post Video on `Twitter` using `Twitterkit` or any other method programmatically in (swift or objective-c). I'v seen many posts related to this but did't find any solution. I don't want use fabric Api.
I'm using below code for uploading image on twitter and it works perfectly, can i use this code for uploading video after modification on it, if any one have idea how i can done this bye using this code.
thanks

```
func post(tweetString: String, tweetImage: Data ,withUserID :String) {

        let uploadUrl = "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json"
        let updateUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"
        let imageString = tweetImage.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions())


        let client = TWTRAPIClient.init(userID: withUserID)

        let requestUploadUrl = client.urlRequest(withMethod: "POST", url: uploadUrl, parameters: ["media": imageString], error: nil)

        client.sendTwitterRequest(requestUploadUrl) { (urlResponse, data, connectionError) -> Void in
            if connectionError == nil {
                if let mediaDict = self.nsdataToJSON(data: (data! as NSData) as Data as Data as NSData) as? [String : Any] {
                    let media_id = mediaDict["media_id_string"] as! String
                    let message = ["status": tweetString, "media_ids": media_id]

                    let requestUpdateUrl = client.urlRequest(withMethod: "POST", url: updateUrl, parameters: message, error: nil)

                    client.sendTwitterRequest(requestUpdateUrl, completion: { (urlResponse, data, connectionError) -> Void in
                        if connectionError == nil {
                            if let _ = self.nsdataToJSON(data: (data! as NSData) as Data as Data as NSData) as? [String : Any] {
                                print("Upload suceess to Twitter")
                            }
                        }

                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func nsdataToJSON (data: NSData) -> AnyObject? {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: .mutableContainers) as AnyObject
        } catch let myJSONError {
            print(myJSONError)
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags. Your question has nothing to do with the Objective-C programming language.

Comment: @rmaddy  Please don't remove objective-c tag i just need ans it doesn't matter either it in swift or objective-c

Answer (score 1):

Uploading video differs significantly from uploading an image. It's basically a two-step process. First, you upload the video file to Twitter. Second, you create a new tweet that references the uploaded video. Also, you must pay close attention to the Twitter's [requirements](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media#videorecs) for the video's specifications.

[Here](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/blob/master/examples/upload_video.py) is an example using the Python language. It uses the [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI) package.