# How i can use Twitter Session For SLRequest.account as ACAccount

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, acaccount, slrequest

I am using [SLRequest](https://swiftoverflow.blogspot.com/2017/04/upload-video-to-twitter-using-slrequest.html?showComment=1505107929459) for post video on twitter.The problem is that when i add my account to twitter App from setting then my code works after fetching account using `ACAccountStore()`. I am using twitter kit on my app, and also i have user session on it. I don't want that the user sign into twitter app from setting for this purpose. I just want to use that store session for `SLRequest`. 
Can anyone please tell me how i can use `Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()` this for SLRequest as `ACAccount` or any other method for `SLRequest`. I also want to know is there any proper way for setup ACAccount() manually bye using session().

Thanks

Comment: You should not continue to try to use the Social framework to access Twitter in iOS 11. Twitter Kit 3 has instructions for migrating https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/migrate-social-framework - use TWTRAPIClient instead of SLRequest.

Comment: @AndyPiper thanks, have you any idea how i can use TWTRAPIClient for video post or any example?

Comment: Use the TWTRComposerViewController class https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/compose-tweets

Comment: @AndyPiper please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122234/post-video-on-twitter-programmatically)

Comment: The TWTRComposerViewController allows you to add a videoURL when posting the Tweet. Using the visible controller is a better user experience that posting something in the background that a user might not expect (this is in line with Twitter's Developer Policy that states users should not be surprised by apps taking action on their behalf). You can also use TWTRAPIClient and the media/upload endpoints to post video. https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload.

Comment: Sample code on Github for iOS using Twitter Kit https://github.com/twitterdev/Photobooth

Comment: @AndyPiper thanks but i need it programmatically, because i'm developing app like hootsuite.